# Is there any better way to extract value from HTML page other than request.getParameter?

Tags: java, jsp

For extracting textbox (dropdown,check  ,etc..) value to JSP page from HTML we mostly using `request.getParameter`. Is there any other way to do this so that can we reduce page processing time?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. `request.getParameter()` 'extracts values' from an HTTP request, not an HTML page. And what exactly makes you think any other way would reduce 'page processing time'? Or any or processing time? What makes you think 'page processing time' is a problem in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the whole http request as an input and "decode" the headers on your own, using [getInputStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getInputStream()) if the request is POST, or [getRequestURL()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL%28%29) if it's a GET request. However, the method [getParameter()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)) has been implemented to do those things, and I do not think that this function could be further optimized.